# Finding all available IPs in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ip-address

I'm trying to find a way to view all available IP address on any one device?

This is what I used for Android:

```
public String[] getLocalIpAddress()
    {          
        ArrayList<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {    
                        addresses.add(inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString());
                    }
                 }
             }
         } catch (SocketException ex) {
             String LOG_TAG = null;
             Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
         }
         return addresses.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` in `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace

```
List<IPAddress> ips = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
              .Where(x => x.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
              .SelectMany(x => x.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
              .Select(x => x.Address)
              .ToList();
```

OR

```
var  ips = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
           .Where(inf => inf.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
           .Where(inf => inf.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
           .Select(x => new{
                name = x.Name,
                ips = x.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Select(y=>y.Address)
                      .ToList()
           })
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks LB, I'll give that a go! Any ideas how I would then populate an Array with the results? Can I use the LongListViewer to display them?

Comment: GeetAllNetworkInterfaces() is not available to Windows Store Apps. Is there any workaround?